# the difference behaviour in popen and pclose

Tags: c, linux

Recently, I get a strange problem when i used `popen(3)` and `pclose(3)`. Just like this:

```
//a.sh
#!/bin/bash
cat /etc/issue
sleep 3

//b.sh
#!/bin/bash
cat /etc/issue
echo "before sleep"
sleep 3
```

my C program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void) {
1:    FILE *fl = popen("sh a.sh", "r");
2:    FILE *fl = popen("sh b.sh", "r");
      int t = pclose(fl);
      printf("%d\n", t);
      return 0;
}
```

next, i will compile and run this program as 4 steps:

case 1:  comment line 2， then compile and run, the program do not print 0 until the shell cmd terminate.

case 2:  comment line 1， then compile and run, the program will terminate right now and it print 13, that is to say the exit status of `pclose` is 13, i look up the linux errno:

```
13 EACCES +Permission denied
```

samebody would help me and tell me the reason? thanks.

Comment: `pclose` returns the exit status of the child process, not an `errno.h` error value.

Comment: thanks, I will use the WEXITSTATUS macro and WIFEXITED macro

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the [WEXITSTATUS](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/wait.html) macro to get the real return code.

Comment: thanks. I use the WEXITSTATUS macro and it return 0. Whether this indicate that the plose is right? But, why it donot wait the shell terminate?

Comment: Have you also used WIFEXITED? Please read the full man page for the W... macros: http://linux.die.net/man/2/wait

Comment: Agree, you should display the return of all the W.. macros to have more info about your child process.