# Why the pclose(3) don't wait shell command terminate

Tags: c, linux, popen, pclose

I want to test the pclose(3) whether it will wait the shell command terminate.I write two little shell program.

```
//a.sh
#!/bin/bash
sleep 3

//b.sh
#!/bin/bash
echo "something"
sleep 3
```

c program:

```
//ptest.c

#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    char *filename = argv[1];
    char *mode = argv[2];
    FILE *fl = popen(filename, &mode);
    int t = pclose(fl);
    if(WIFEXITED(t)) {
        printf("exit status:%d\n", WEXITSTATUS(t));
    }
    return 0;
}
```

then, compile:
    $ gcc -o ptest ptest.c

next run the ptest(my computer is Ubuntu 12.04.3 LTS）:

```
$ ./ptest "sh a.sh" r
$ exit status:0
```

this test will **wait the shell terminate** and output exit status 0.However when I run the ptest as following form:

```
$ ./ptest "sh b.sh" r
$ exit status:141
```

this time, ptest don't wait shell program and terminate itself immediately， I just add an echo statement before the sleep, But the result was different. I don't know why .

Comment: Didn't you ask [the same question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/20607398/464709) a few hours ago?

Comment: Maybe it's an I/O issue. Try to `fgets()` your file descriptor (see the [example](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7999959899/functions/popen.html)).

Comment: From what do you conclude the shell terminated or not?

Comment: It [works properly on my system](http://www.buildsonmymachine.com/). Check file permissions for b.sh ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`exit status:141` is a `SIGPIPE` error. It is well explained in this question [Why exit code 141 with grep -q?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19120263/why-exit-code-141-with-grep-q)

The issue is that your `b.sh` script tries to write to the pipe, but nobody is reading this pipe in your C program.

Comment: But, as the apue said:"If we write to a pipe whose read end has been closed, the signal SIGPIPEis generated" on the chapter 15.2, in my case, I don't close the read end and just don't read the pipe.  
In addition, when I call the pclose(3), the echo command in the b.sh has finished possibility.